# Using BETWEEN function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query, using which I am trying to categorize my data. If the first character is between 0 and 9, I want to categorize it with the first character. If it is anything else including special characters or alphabets, then I want to use 10.

```
select CUSTOMER_ID, CASE
                    WHEN LEFT(CUSTOMER_ID, 1) BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN LEFT(CUSTOMER_ID, 1)
                    ELSE '10'
                END
                AS CUST_DIGIT
 from CUSTOMER
```

I get this error when I run the above query:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'A' to data type
>   int.

This is what my data looks like. Could you please help point what I could change.

[image]

Comment: By comparing with number, you force cast to number of the result of LEFT(...) : add quotes to `'0' AND '9'`

Comment: And the mandatory [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your between values to `string` as `'0' AND '9'` then it will work.

Reason you are getting error is when you perform `LEFT` it will return `string` and you are comparing it with `int` as `0 AND 9` are `int`, So it will try to convert your result value from `LEFT` to `int`.

Your some of the record have `digit` at beginning of value those will work fine but when record comes like `A46564` it won't be able to `cast` `A` to `int` and throw `error`.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, CASE
                        WHEN LEFT(CUSTOMER_ID, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN LEFT(CUSTOMER_ID, 1)
                        ELSE '10'
                    END AS CUST_DIGIT
FROM CUSTOMER
```

Answer (score 3):

I would initially answer the same as [@Karan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9695286).

Just for completeness... In your case, a possible alternative would be to use `ISNUMERIC`:

```sql
select
  CUSTOMER_ID,
  CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(CUSTOMER_ID, 1)) = 1 THEN LEFT(CUSTOMER_ID, 1)
    ELSE '10'
  END AS CUST_DIGIT
from
  CUSTOMER
```

And yet another approach would be to use the `LIKE` operator:

```sql
select
  CUSTOMER_ID,
  CASE
    WHEN CUSTOMER_ID LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN LEFT(CUSTOMER_ID, 1)
    ELSE '10'
  END AS CUST_DIGIT
from
  CUSTOMER
```

Comment: This is actually a better approach.

Comment: @Karan . . . In this case perhaps... But using a `BETWEEN ... AND ...` expression might be more flexible if you want to check specific numerical value ranges instead of 0..9.

Comment: @Karan . . . I just added another alternative. Not sure what's best, however, but at least it's more compact and (arguably) more expressive.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` returns notoriously many false positives. E.g. `SELECT ISNUMERIC('-')` (which value occurs in the sample data) returns `1`

Comment: @HoneyBadger . . . 8-O... That's shocking! Thanks for this hint! I will think about it if I ever use it again. (Gladly I very rarely use `ISNUMERIC`, and I only use it in ad-hoc queries where I always manually check the results.) It does make me curious what (and how) Microsoft was thinking when they initially implemented this function...

Comment: @BartHofland, the reasoning is pretty straightforward. The function checks whether the value can be converted to *any* numeric datatype, that includes `money`. Its just not a very intuitive function.

Comment: @HoneyBadger . . . Aha...I see! I never use the `money` data types, so I did not know that.Thank you so much for your help in this regard. :)